# How to get values from one table that are not being used by top 3 results in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2019

I need to figure out what beers from table 'Beer' were not ordered by top 3 buyers from table 'Buyers'.
Beer.BeerId is foreign key in Buyers.BeerId.
Other important columns in 'Buyers' are: BuyId, PubId, StoreId and Quantity

dbo.Beer

| BeerId |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

dbo.Buyers

| BuyId | PubId | StoreId | BeerId | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NULL | 1 | 30 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | 2 | 40 |
| 3 | 2 | NULL | 3 | 50 |
| 4 | NULL | 2 | 4 | 10 |

I tried doing this query but it gives me no results.

```
SELECT Be.BeerId
    FROM Beer be
    left outer join Buyer bu
    ON be.BeerId=bu.BeerId
WHERE not exists (
        SELECT TOP(3) BuyId, bu.BeerId, 
            SUM(Quantity) as TotalOrdered
        FROM Buyer bu
        GROUP BY BuyId, bu.BeerId
        ORDER BY SUM(Quantity) DESC)
```

What I would expect to see is that from the top 3 results, beers that are not ordered are BeerId=4 and BeerId=5

Comment: please share the expected result set from above table.

Comment: As I understand the problem, you need to approach the solution in three steps: (1) Who are the top three buyers. (2) What beers did those top three buyers buy. (3) What beers in the beers table are not included in the step 2 results. Note that some buyers may buy a large quantity of a single beer, while others may spread their consumption across a variety, so the number of beers from step 2 may be greater than the number of buyers (three) selected in step 1. Also, a top buyer might only buy one of the beers once, but that still qualifies as a beer selected in step 2. Step 3 should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a classic [window function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) problem. You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to enumerate the rows in order of their `Quantity` totals descending, and filter out the top 3 like so:

```
WITH _BuyersTotalsRanked AS
(
    SELECT 
        BeerId, -- Same BeerId might've been ordered by different Buyers
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalOrderedPerBeer DESC) AS BuyersRanked
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            BeerId, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalOrderedPerBeer
        FROM dbo.Buyer
        GROUP BY BuyId, BeerId
    ) AS BuyersTotals
)

SELECT DISTINCT BeerId -- Same BeerId might've been ordered by different Buyers
FROM _BuyersTotalsRanked
WHERE BuyersRanked > 3 -- Filter out the top 3 Buyers Beers
```

Note that if there's a tie for the top 3, this will return nondeterminsitic (semi-random) results because of the `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER()` function not being unique (same problem with your `ORDER BY` clause in your example query).

To correct that, you would need to add a uniquifying field to deterministically decide which row *wins* in a tie. Usually you would use the key of the table. I'm not sure what the key is for your `dbo.Buyer` table. But whatever it is, or whichever combination of fields are unique, you can update the `ROW_NUMBER()` clause like so `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TotalOrderedPerBeer DESC, UnqiueSetOfFields)`. Then those fields would be used to determine the winning row(s) in a tie.

---

Alternatively, if when there are ties for top 3, and you want to exclude all of those ties as well, you can use a different window function such as [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) like so:

```
WITH _BuyersTotalsRanked AS
(
    SELECT 
        BeerId,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalOrderedPerBeer DESC) AS BuyersRanked
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            BeerId, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalOrderedPerBeer
        FROM dbo.Buyer
        GROUP BY BuyId, BeerId
    ) AS BuyersTotals
)

SELECT DISTINCT BeerId -- Same BeerId might've been ordered by different Buyers
FROM _BuyersTotalsRanked
WHERE BuyersRanked > 3 -- Filter out the top 3 Buyers Beers
```

`DENSE_RANK()` will enumerate all tied rows with the same value, instead of randomly deciding which one comes first like `ROW_NUMBER()` does.

---

Finally, your question (and data / schema) is a little unclear. Based on your example code, I'm interpreting that what you're asking for is to exclude the top 3 `Buyer`s of any single `Beer`, not top 3 by their told purchases of all `Beer`s. E.g. `Buyer1` may have only purchased one type of beer, `BeerA` for a quantity of 50, but `Buyer2` purchased two types of beer, `BeerB` for 30, and `BeerC` for 40. In the above code (and your attempted code) `Buyer1` would be ranked #1 even though `Buyer2` has a greater total purchase of `Beer`s, totaling 70.

If you wanted to rank the `Buyer`s by their total purchases across all `Beer`s, then you'd want to do something like the following:

```
WITH _BuyersTotalsRanked AS
(
    SELECT 
        BuyId,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalOrderedAll DESC) AS BuyersRanked
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            BuyId, 
            SUM(Quantity) AS TotalOrderedAll
        FROM dbo.Buyer
        GROUP BY BuyId
    ) AS BuyersTotals
)

SELECT DISTINCT B.BeerId -- Same BeerId might've been ordered by different Buyers
FROM dbo.Buyer AS B
INNER JOIN _BuyersTotalsRanked AS BTR
    ON B.BuyId = BTR.BuyId
WHERE B.BuyersRanked > 3 -- Filter out the top 3 Buyers Beers
```

Comment: To properly handle the tie case, I believe `RANK()` should be used instead of `DENSE_RANK()`. Otherwise a tie for 1st or 2nd would unnecessarily pull in a 4th top buyer. (Either would pull in a 4th in a tie for 3rd.)  See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7rTf4p6F).

Comment: @TN That's a fair point but also depends on how OP wants to handle ties / how they define what *top 3* should be. If they wanted the top 3 *distinct* `TotalOrderedAll` then `DENSE_RANK()` would be correct, otherwise `RANK()` could be used. Both solutions can result in more than 3 rows being returned though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (3)BeerId 
from (
SELECT BeerId, SUM(Quantity) Be.BeerId
    FROM Beer be
    left outer join Buyer bu
    ON be.BeerId=bu.BeerId
Group by BeerId) my_derived_table
ORDER BY BeerId
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.